# Round Output to whole Number

Tags: jquery, datepicker, rounding

I have a JQuery datepicker that outputs the number of nights in a span tag however sometimes the number comes out as a whole and sometimes a decimal. How would I got about amending this script so that the number of nights output is always a whole number of days.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    // check-out date >= check-in date
    function customRange(dates) { 
        if (this.id == 'startdate') { 
            jQuery('#enddate').datepick('option', 'minDate', dates[0] || null); 
        } 
        else { 
            jQuery('#startdate').datepick('option', 'maxDate', dates[0] || null); 
        }
        var edt = jQuery('#ed_timestamp').val();
        var sdt = jQuery('#sd_timestamp').val();
        if ((edt > 0) && (sdt > 0)) {
            jQuery('span.nights').text((edt - sdt) / (3600*24) + ' night(s)');
        } else {
            jQuery('span.nights').text('');
        }
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        // Datepick input fields
        jQuery('#startdate').datepick({
            onSelect: customRange, 
            showTrigger: '#trigger',
            altField: '#sd_timestamp', 
            altFormat: jQuery.datepick.TIMESTAMP
        });
        jQuery('#enddate').datepick({
            onSelect: customRange, 
            showTrigger: '#trigger',
            altField: '#ed_timestamp', 
            altFormat: jQuery.datepick.TIMESTAMP
        });



    });

    //]]>
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Math.round(numberVariable);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get date objects from the datepicker using `getDate`, then calculate the difference as follows:

```
var edt = jQuery('#ed_timestamp').datepicker('getDate');
var sdt = jQuery('#sd_timestamp').datepicker('getDate');

Math.ceil((edt.getTime()-sdt.getTime())/1000*60*60*24)
```

Note 1000*60*60*24 is milliseconds in one day.

See - 
JavaScript Date - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp and calculating the difference between two dates - http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/datedifference.shtml